# Accessing nested JSON inside a GitHub actions matrix

Tags: github-actions

Having the following code snippet:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  step1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.build.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: build
      run: echo "matrix=[{\"project\":\"foo\",\"config\":\"Debug\"},{\"project\":\"bar\",\"config\":\"Release\"}]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  step2:
    needs: step1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        include: ${{fromJson(needs.step1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo hello
```

Is it possible to access individual values like `project` instead of the entire JSON object when setting up the matrix `include: ${{fromJson(needs.step1.outputs.matrix)}}`?

Also but not included in the example, how would this be done for a nested JSON object inside the JSON formatted string?

Comment: Please include the example for nested JSON as well. For this, did you try using the index operator `[]` and then dereference the property using the dereference operator `.` e.g. `fromJson(needs.step1.outputs.matrix)[0].project`? See [Operators](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators). (Not tested)

Comment: @Azeem Using the index operator does not seem to work as that does not return a sequence. `Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'test'. .github/workflows/test.yml (Line: 30, Col: 18): Unexpected type of value 'foo', expected type: Sequence.`

Comment: You have to match it according to your actual matrix. You can utilize [`format()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) to create a raw JSON that you need and then [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) again to make it a valid JSON array (sequence).

Comment: @Azeem if you can provide a solution answer I have something I can accept as an answer. :)

Comment: It's trial and error. Please update your question with all the details. I'll try to look into it on my side later. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Within the workflow context outside of a `shell`, you can utilize [functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions) such as [`toJSON()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson), [`fromJSON()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson), and [`join()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#join) along with [operators](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) such as `.` (property dereference), and `[]` (index operator) in conjunction with [object filters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#object-filters) wherever needed.

Within `shell`, you can utilize functions, operators, and object filters as well as the [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) command line utility for more flexibility and complex JSON manipulation.

Here's a sample workflow:

```yaml
name: populate_matrix_from_json

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  step1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.setup.outputs.matrix }}

    steps:
    - name: Setup
      id: setup
      env:
        CONFIG: >-
          [
            {
              "project": "foo",
              "config": "Debug",
              "nested": [
                {
                  "val": "val1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "project": "bar",
              "config": "Release",
              "nested": [
                {
                  "val": "val2"
                },
                {
                  "val": "val3"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
      run: echo "matrix=$(jq -r -c . <<< "$CONFIG")" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    
    - name: Check
      run: jq . <<< '${{ steps.setup.outputs.matrix }}'

  step2:
    needs: step1

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix: 
        include: ${{ fromJSON(needs.step1.outputs.matrix) }}

    steps:
    - name: Check
      env:
        MATRIX: ${{ toJSON(matrix) }}
        PROJECT: ${{ fromJSON(toJSON(matrix)).project }}
        CONFIG: ${{ fromJSON(toJSON(matrix)).config }}
        NESTED: ${{ join(fromJSON(toJSON(matrix)).nested.*.val, ', ') }}
      run: |
        echo "MATRIX: $(jq -r -c '.' <<< "$MATRIX")"
        echo "PROJECT: [$PROJECT]"
        echo "CONFIG: [$CONFIG]"
        echo "NESTED: [$NESTED]"
```

**Output** (`step2` - 1):

[image: step2 - 1]

**Output** (`step2` - 2):

[image: step2 - 2]