# Loop over object array nested inside a matrix in GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, github-actions, cicd

Having the following code:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  step1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.build.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: build
      run: echo "matrix=[{\"project\":\"foo\",\"config\":\"Debug\",\"nested\":[{\"val\":\"val1\"}]},{\"project\":\"bar\",\"config\":\"Release\",\"nested\":[{\"val\":\"val2\"},{\"val\":\"val3\"}]}]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  step2:
    needs: step1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        include: ${{fromJson(needs.step1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo hello
```

Is it possible to iterate over the nested array and display it's values? I would like to replace `echo hello` with a loop that outputs the content of the array's as follows(2 nested array's):

```
iteration 1:
val1
iteration 2:
val2
val3
```

Comment: How do you want to use these exactly? Same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704312/accessing-nested-json-inside-a-github-actions-matrix)?

Comment: In shell, with `jq`, you can get all three values like this: `echo '${{ steps.build.outputs.matrix }}' | jq -r '.[].nested[].val'`. Check it live here: https://jqplay.org/s/KICtFMPVBuJ.

Comment: You can get specific value e.g. `project` like this: `PROJECT: ${{ fromJson(needs.step1.outputs.matrix)[0].project }}`

Answer (score 1):

For all values, you can get those from `${{ steps.build.outputs.matrix }}`.

In `shell`, with `jq`, you can get all three values like this:

```bash
echo '${{ steps.build.outputs.matrix }}' | jq -r '.[].nested[].val'
```

Combined output:

```
val1
val2
val3
```

Live: https://jqplay.org/s/KICtFMPVBuJ

---

For job specific values, you can utilize `${{ toJSON(matrix) }}` and filter it:

```bash
echo '${{ toJSON(matrix) }}' | jq -r '.nested[].val'

# Output 1:
# val1

# Output 2:
# val2
# val3
```